# Why is it that when the canvas height is very large, the origin is offset?

Tags: three.js

Using an orthographic camera, I drew a grid and a red rectangle in the center of the canvas and a black square at the top of the canvas. When the canvas height is not high, everything is normal, but when the canvas height is very large, the grid and red rectangle will not be in the center of the view.

When the height is very high, an offset occurs  -- var height = 40000

When the height is average, everything is normal  -- var height = 800

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="../three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #webGL {
            width: 1568px;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="webGL">

        </div>
    <script>
        /* Boilerplate */
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var width = 1568  
        var height = 40000  //When the height is very high, an offset occurs
        //var height = 800  //When the height is average, everything is normal

        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-width/2,width/2,height/2,-height/2,1,8000)
        camera.position.set(0,100,0)
        camera.up.set(0,0,1)
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true
        });
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        renderer.setClearColor("white")

        document.getElementById("webGL").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        let testGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200,200)
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'black',side: THREE.DoubleSide})
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(testGeom,material)
        cube.rotation.x+=Math.PI/2
        cube.position.z = height/2
        scene.add(cube);

        let origin  = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,50)
        let originMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'red',side:THREE.DoubleSide})
        let originMesh = new THREE.Mesh(origin,originMaterial)
        originMesh.rotation.x+=Math.PI/2
        scene.add(originMesh)

        scene.position.set(0,0,0)
        var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(80,5,0x000ff,0x808080) //size,step
        scene.add(helper)
        var flag = false
        var render = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        render();
        //console.log(scene,camera,renderer)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).